# Image from external website not displaying on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am using an api to get an an image and then I am trying to display that image. The source the api returns works but when displaying it on my page it does not show.

```
<img class="avi" src="' + data.data[0].musicbrainz_image_url + '"/>
```

This the line that is displaying it but I do not see why it will not display. Any ideas?

Edit: Here is the whole code. I am using JQuery to output the html with the data from the API.

```
$.ajax({
       type: "GET",
        data: {
            api_key:"69abb9ae8bc1af849baf2a2890e08d08",
            name: artistSearch,
            limit: 1,

        },
        url: "http://api.musicgraph.com/api/v2/artist/search",
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.data[0].name);
            var myHTML = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
                myHTML += '<li class="artistName  list-group-item">';
                myHTML += '<span class="name">' + data.data[0].name + '</span></br>';
                myHTML += '<span class="country">Country of Origin: ' + data.data[0].country_of_origin + '</span></br>';
                myHTML += '<span class="country">Decade: ' + data.data[0].decade + '</span></br>';
                myHTML += '<span class="country">Genre of Music: ' + data.data[0].main_genre + '</span></br>';
                myHTML += '<img class="avi" src="' + data.data[0].musicbrainz_image_url + '"/>';
                myHTML += '</div>';
                myHTML += '</li>';
            }
            $('#artist_output').append(myHTML);
```

Edit 2:

myHTML variable:

```
<li class="artistName  list-group-item">
<span class="name">Drake</span></br>
<span class="country">Country of Origin: Canada</span></br>
<span class="country">Decade: 2000s / 2010s</span></br><
span class="country">Genre of Music: Rap/Hip Hop</span></br> 
<img class="avi"src="https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Drake_at_Bun-B_Concert_2011.jpg"/>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: What language are you using? Is there any more code you can show?

Comment: Is your snippet a piece of a larger string? As in, is the API returning a giant HTML string and this is just a piece of it?

Comment: @j08691 no console errors. Image just displays with the generic not found picture

Comment: @Tony I have updated with more code. It is Javascript/JQuery

Comment: @Santi Yes it is part of a larger piece of code. The API is returning JSON and I am writing html around it and outputting it. I have updated with more code.

Comment: What's the actual final result of your `myHTML` variable?

Comment: @j08691 it is building a table with spots for different pieces of data and then it will output it to a div on the page. It works correctly but the image does not display.

Comment: Can you post the console.log of that variable?

Comment: @j08691 updated

Comment: The link `https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Drake_at_Bun-B_Concert_2011.jpg` loads a page for me, not an image. The image is at `https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6c/Drake_at_Bun-B_Concert_2011.jpg`

Comment: @j08691 I see now yes you are correct. Shame then because that is the link the api returns so I suppose that feature is effectively useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The img url you are using:

https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Drake_at_Bun-B_Concert_2011.jpg

is not an image, it is an HTML page. You need to figure out how to get just the url directly to the image, like this:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/6c/Drake_at_Bun-B_Concert_2011.jpg/489px-Drake_at_Bun-B_Concert_2011.jpg

instead.

Comment: Ah makes sense. It is a shame then because that is what the api returns for most queries which makes it useless.